# Resize image with carrierwave ignoring the aspect ratio - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

How do I resize an image using carrierwave and minimagick so that it ignores the aspect ratio?,
I want a [120,120] image

(The linked answer maintains aspect ratio, I want to ignore aspect ratio!!)

Comment: This does NOT answer my question as I specifically asked for aspect ratio to be ignored and your linked answer maintains aspect ratio.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to write a custom processing method in your uploader:

```
class MyImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  version :square do
    process my_resize: [120, 120]
  end

  def my_resize(width, height)
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.resize "#{width}x#{height}!"
      img
    end
  end

end
```

The `resize` method uses [ImageMagick geometry syntax](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry). So in this case the exclamation mark at the end tells ImageMagick to ignore the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resize_to_fill: [120, 120]`. That will ignore the aspect ratio so the resulting image would be 120x120

Don't confound with `resize_to_fit: [120, 120]` that will keep the aspect ratio, so the resulting image could be 120x90 (depending on aspect ratio).

Hope this helped